# Python - Check if two values(strings) are both in dict

Tags: python

Here is dict:

```
a = {u'jQuery': {'categories': [u'javascript-frameworks']},
 u'Twitter Bootstrap': {'categories': [u'web-frameworks']},
 u'WooCommerce': {'categories': [u'ecommerce']},
 u'mod_ssl': {'categories': [u'web-server-extensions']},
 u'Font Awesome': {'categories': [u'font-scripts']}, 
 u'Modernizr': {'categories': [u'javascript-frameworks']},
 u'OpenSSL': {'categories': [u'web-server-extensions']},
 u'AddThis': {'categories': [u'widgets']},
 u'UNIX': {'categories': [u'operating-systems']},
 u'Gravatar': {'categories': [u'miscellaneous']},
 u'Google Font API': {'categories': [u'font-scripts']},
 u'Apache': {'categories': [u'web-servers']},
 u'WordPress': {'categories': [u'cms', u'blogs']},
 u'PHP': {'categories': [u'programming-languages']}}
```

I need to get True if both 'cms' and 'ecommerce' are present in whole dict.

I tried this way:

```
for key, value in a.items():        
    if 'cms' in value['categories'] and 'ecommerce' in value['categories']:
        print 'lala'
```

And:

```
for key, value in a.items():        
    if 'cms' and 'ecommerce' in value['categories']:
        print 'in'
```

With this approach it prints 'in' even if 'cms' is not present. I want it to only proceed if both strings are present.

Comment: only the first one can work, maybe missing `u` ?

Comment: If missing `u` was a problem, it would always return `False`. The first one works just fine.

Comment: Your second attempt essentially translates to `if 'cms' is not None and 'ecommerce' in value['categories']`, which will always be `True`. The missing `u` is not the problem.

Comment: yeah 'u' is not the problem I think. If there is no added(and.....) it prints.

Comment: Are you sure the first one doesn't work? It doesn't print anything but there are no entries that match. If I add one, it prints.

Comment: The first method looks good, but you have no items that are both 'cms' and 'ecommerce' in your list...

Comment: Yeah, the first one works.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich pretty sure now that this is the issue, any ideas on how to recheck the whole dict again if any other item has second value?

Comment: I tried doing this: `a['WordPress']['categories'].append(u'ecommerce'])`. The first version prints just fine. What is the problem?

Comment: @NemaGa: you're confusing us -- your code checks if there is one value that has both 'cms' and 'ecommerce' in its categories list, is that not what you want to do?

Comment: You need to find both values across the whole dict (eg.: they may be below different keys) or they need to be under the same key? Your first attempt is trying to find them under the same key.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich yeah, should said it differently... I wanted to check if both are present in entire a dict not just in specific item inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether they are present in the whole dict, I would make a set of all the categories in the whole dict, and use that:

```
all_categories = {
    category
    for value in a.values() for category in value['categories']
}

if 'cms' in all_categories and 'ecommerce' in all_categories:
    print("Yes, that strange order of for clauses is actually correct...")
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. My bad explaining it poorly :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that's purely an expression without side-effects:

```
test = ( any([ u'cms' in c.get('categories') for c in a.values() ]) and
         any([ u'ecommerce' in c.get('categories') for c in a.values() ]) )
```

note: change to `c.get('categories',[])` if the code is to run OK should some of the `a.values()` not contain the key 'categories'.

Comment: Nice. You can get rid of the `[` and `]` inside the `any`, so that it becomes a generator expression and doesn't have to build a list.

Comment: Thanks. It's probably clearer with `[` and `]` but definitely less efficient.